# Kusto query design join small table output with large table with time range

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics

Looking for suggestions to build an optimized KQL query for the following scenario:

Have an Incident table which I will filter to the service I own so the output will be ~100 records with following schema:

```
| Incident Time | Deployment Unit Id |
```

I have to join this to a telemetry table that has millions of events from various services which I can filter to my service but still the event volume will be huge. I have to find the failure event for the Incident above based on failure events that occurred within 2 mins of Incident Time for the Deployment Unit and get the Event message for every Incident.

```
| Event Time | Deployment Unit Id | Event Message
```

Tried join but it needs == which I can't because the Event Time and Incident Time won't match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple technics to handle a time-window join.
The following technic generates 3 instances of each record in the 1st table (the small table, `Incidents`), binned to the requested time-window and join it with the binned record of the 2nd table (the big table, `Telemetry`)

`hint.strategy=broadcast` might improve performance in some use-cases.

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let Incidents = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend IncidentTime = ago(rand()*365d*10), DeploymentUnitId = toint(rand(1000)));
let Telemetry = materialize(range i from 1 to 10000000 step 1 | extend EventTime = ago(rand()*365d*10), DeploymentUnitId = toint(rand(1000)), EventMessage = tostring(new_guid()));
// Solution starts here.
let p_time_window = 2m;
Incidents
| mv-expand i = range(-1, 1) to typeof(int)
| extend dttm_bin = bin(IncidentTime + i * p_time_window, p_time_window)
| join kind=inner hint.strategy=broadcast (Telemetry | extend dttm_bin = bin(EventTime, p_time_window)) on DeploymentUnitId, dttm_bin
| where  around(IncidentTime, EventTime, p_time_window)
| project DeploymentUnitId, IncidentTime, EventTime, EventMessage
```

| DeploymentUnitId | IncidentTime | EventTime | EventMessage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 393 | 2013-09-16T01:19:09.9558462Z | 2013-09-16T01:17:30.7996592Z | 28b5109e-a28e-4a55-bb59-c413a6cee3d5 |
| 395 | 2021-09-05T09:51:51.7889672Z | 2021-09-05T09:52:41.6527372Z | ce4f72cc-262a-4616-baf6-ec6a1141e05f |
| 182 | 2021-09-16T02:17:18.7904512Z | 2021-09-16T02:19:09.1824542Z | b162f8d6-14b0-45f6-abfd-ca239700968a |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA61SsW7CMBDdkfiHG2MaSNKqXapsdGBol7ZzZMgRTGM7sg9CKj6%20l4BSQCB16BLplPfevffOUQRTSRK81FWJUKBBJ0lZM4E3S1BJR2CXQCsEb8tN92c4KJFgZhYqR0MeUtCS0ClZqm8MnDQFgoKlsxoSIAtJHMfgCSse94A7QpP39A%20lkRVkYVtmHojRw9NjPkpiEcIUq9I2mlGfRtEsZxxZZeiAbGWFEM8HO4QlaiTX/MlOfM3Sy/Yf/IQHmVf0XhbYITw5ZYrAYJ0VG8WSnekogvdjo%20yEe/awQofHdquM2EhWK5PbmlXuNVP6yoeDPejtGHcVL%20ZwKXQxg3ESQiLakNRUaJcBmxMt%20JgwJ9LZXBkm8Dc4u8Ed64zO94bnY6e05sDwxXOqDL8VWPGKCSfkyosmnTsr84X0BMHvQW6t7/u%203COAO7ksO%20zprY267QpAOrvh6k%20DhHBTtyVWzq5xQVfkb4qcHvQHeu8G4TADAAA=)